# How to specify order of combined charts in c3.js?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I'm building a combined chart of type area and bar. The bar part of the chart is appearing under the area part so it becomes covered by the area part. Like this:

[image: chart with order problem]

I want to bring the bars in front of the area.

I've tried changing the order in `data.order` but it does not work.

The expected result is this:

[image: chart with order problem]

In the inspector, if I change the order of the elements manually so that `c3-charts-bars` is after `c3-charts-lines` I get the expected result but, does anyone know how to do that using the `c3.js` API?

Comment: There is a solution on this GitHub issue: https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1938 , I don't think it's very clean, but it will do it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually using [react-c3](https://github.com/bcbcarl/react-c3js) to wrap the c3 library so my solution was based on the [GitHub](https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/1938) issue solution.

```
...
oninit: () => {
    let container = ReactDom.findDOMNode(this);
    let chart = container.getElementsByClassName('c3-chart')[0];
    let bars = chart.getElementsByClassName('c3-chart-bars')[0];
    bars.parentNode.append(bars);
},
...
```